# Submeter dados de um input box usando a tecla enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quero que ao apertar a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> o valor seja inserido na página HTML usando jQuery.

O código abaixo é `input` simples em HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Somar Arrays</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section class="vetores">
      <p>Adicione números:</p>
      <input type="text"><button>+</button>
    </section>

    <section class= "imprimir"></section>

      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="funcao.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

O código abaixo, em JavaScript, permite que valores sejam inseridos com o click do mouse, mas como fazer funcionar quando aperto a tecla <kbd>enter</kbd>?

```
var main = function() {
        "use strict";

    //Permite que os valores sejam inseridos a partir do click do mouse
        $(".vetores button").on("click", function(event){
            var $nro;

                if ($(".vetores input").val() !== "") {
                    $nro = $("<p>").text($(".vetores input").val());
                    $(".imprimir").append($nro);
                    $(".vetores input").val("");
                }
        });

    //Permite que os valores sejam inseridos a partir da tecla enter
        $(".vetores button").on("keypress", function(event){
            var $nro;

            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                if ($(".vetores input").val() !== "") {
                    $nro = $("<p>").text($(".vetores input").val());
                    $(".imprimir").append($nro);
                    $(".vetores input").val("");
                }
            }
    });

    };

    $(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O evento de keypress deve ser associado ao input, e não ao botão.

Troque de:

```
$(".vetores button").on("keypress", function(event){
```

Para:

```
$(".vetores input").on("keypress", function(event){
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!